# ASP NET API - Authenticate users using Azure AD SAML Protocol without open Microsoft Login Page

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, saml

It's my first time with Azure AD and SAML protocol, I want to know if it's possible to add a user authentication request to Azure AD without being redirecting to Microsoft Login Page? If so, how it can be done?

Basically, I want to send the email and password and authenticate to Azure without leaving the page of my Mobile application

[image: Azure SAML Configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SAML specification supports the SP sending the user name in the SAML authn request to the IdP. However, not all IdPs support this. The SAML specification does not support sending the password. Therefore, unless the user is already logged in at the IdP, they will always be prompted to enter their password.